# Java application hangs while using NFS

Tags: java, nfs

Currently we are using java 1.6.45 and NFS version4 on a solaris 10 node. The mounts are soft mounts with read only permission.

We have many application deployed on the same node. One application which is using these mounts is getting hanged, as we are not getting any logs and thread dumps with jstack or kill -3.

Only jstack -F is reporting some output but that too are not very helpful. Almost all application threads are in BLOCKED state.

There are no logs in dmesg related to NFS. But we are doubting NFS only to be the root cause of the issue.

The issue is getting resolved with application restart, but I doubt that there is anything fishy with the application, as the same code which is running on some other node without using NFS communication is working perfectly fine.

Can anyone help that how it can be confirmed that issue is because of NFS only?

Comment: Try reading the same files, not in Java.

Comment: I fear: nobody can (well, unless there is maybe a known defect somewhere for exactly that setup). But the problem is: it could be anything in your stack. One would need some real domain expert ... sitting **in front** of your system to do the debugging ...

Comment: Probably not related, but after copying onto a ext4 based RAID file from a NTFS partition, I had same kind of trouble in my process: I had to use a specific {{ExecutorService}} to provide me {{InputStream}} with a timeout of 2s. Some time after, I've seen that I had pipe file and Java was tried to do something. You should check the type of each file on which you block or find all non directory/file using {{find -not '(' -type f -or -type d ')'}} (this does not ignore links).

Comment: Once checked what @PeterLawrey suggests, why don't you try some alternative solution?  Is it possible to mount the same fs with SAMBA in your network and try your process against that setup?

Comment: @Jorge_B - It is not possible to replace NFS with SAMBA as it is live environment.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - The files we are reading are simple plain text files. Are you suggesting to read those files directly without using the JAVA code?

Comment: @Minta can you read them in any other program without a problem? i.e. does it have anything to do with Java?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - We have not tried that... Other thing, this issue is getting resolved with the application restart.

Comment: @Minta there is nothing the JVM does which is special for NFS, and it is not possible in pure Java to even determine you are using NFS at all.